# Obtener un array mas simple en cakephp x2

Tags: php, array, cakephp

Espero puedan ayudarme,

yo estoy haciendo una consulta query:

```
    $gh = $this->Hcxestablishment->query("SELECT con_january + eme_january + ext_january as suma FROM 
hcxestablishments WHERE regions_id = $reg && year = $yer");
```

y esta consulta me devuelve un array estructurado de esta forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [suma] => 93
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [suma] => 1403
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [suma] => 693
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [suma] => 837
                )

        )

    [4] => Array .... aqui continua hasta terminar con los datos de la tabla.
```

Yo necesito poder obtener ese array en un formato mas simple, como por ejemplo asi.

```
[0] => 93
[1] => 1403
[3] => 837
[4] => .....
```

He estado probando con el tipo de find 'list' de cakephp - 2.x para obtener ese formato de array pero me da error al momento de poner una suma de columnas en el fields.

```
$hcxestablishments = $this->Hcxestablishment->find(
            'list',
            array(
                'fields' => array('con_january + eme_january + ext_january'),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Hcxestablishment.year =' => $yer,
                    'Hcxestablishment.regions_id ' => $reg
                ),
            )
        );
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien sabe de alguna forma de hacer esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado podrías intentar creando una función que procese tu arreglo y lo formatee a la estructura que deseas.

```
$a_response = array(
    array(
        array(
            "suma" => 123
            )
        ),
        array(
        array(
            "suma" => 456
            )
        ),
        array(
        array(
            "suma" => 789
            )
        ),
    );
    
function getSuma($arreglo)
{
    $a_temp = array();
    
    foreach($arreglo as $arr)
    {
        $a_temp[] = $arr[0]["suma"];
    }
    return $a_temp;
}

$a_results = getSuma($a_response);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a_results);
```

Eso debería retornar lo siguiente:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono tu respuesta.